# MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }" at path "favorites"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

i took https://github.com/zarkomaslaric/yelpcamp-likes this as my reference and tried to make a favorite campground system in which the user if favorite any campground the object id will be stored in user model
here is what i tried
https://www.filehosting.org/file/details/859839/yelpcamp-favorites-master.rar (some of the things like moongoose are setup according to older versions)
the error i am getting is

```
events.js:288
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
MongooseError [CastError]: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }" at path "favorites"
    at new CastError (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\cast.js:29:11)
    at ObjectId.cast (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\objectid.js:232:11)
    at ObjectId.SchemaType.applySetters (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:845:12)
    at Array._cast (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:129:32)
    at Array._mapCast (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:308:17)
    at Arguments.map (<anonymous>)
    at Array.push (c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\array.js:322:25)
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\routes\campgrounds.js:84:28
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4687:16
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4095:12
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2682:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11)
Emitted 'error' event on Function instance at:
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4689:13
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4095:12
    at c:\Users\ronni\Downloads\Compressed\yelpcamp-likes-master\yelpcamp-favorites-master\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:2682:28
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:79:11) {
  message: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }" at path "favorites"`,
  name: 'CastError',
  stringValue: `"{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }"`,
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: { id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' },
  path: 'favorites',
  reason: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems the favorites is an array of `objectIds`,

and you passed an object to it `{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }` while it expects and accepts only `objectIds`

you need to pass the _id directly to the favorites array instead of passing an object `{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }`

just pass this `'5e9485557841553e6806b6e1'` to the `favorites` array

instead of passing this `"{ id: '5e9485557841553e6806b6e1' }"`